# Using Git, how do I create a list of patches that contains only changes in a certain directory?

Tags: git

I am trying to apply Julia's patches to Femtolisp.  However, Julia has kept its version within its own source control tree.  Therefore, tools like `git format-patch` don't work, since they don't allow filtering by directory.

Is my best option to write a script to filter out the unwanted patches, or does Git have this functionality built-in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a GIT command that does what you need, but you can use a few commands and a bit of shell to do the work.
Something like the following:

```
$ mkdir mypatches
$ N=1
$ for x in $(git rev-list FROM_COMMIT..TO_COMMIT)
  do
      P=$(git diff $x^..$x -- DIRECTORY)
      if [ -n "$P" ]
      then
          echo "$P" > mypatches/$(printf %06d $N).patch
          N=$((N+1))
      fi
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **git diff** command to get a difference between two folders ...

```
git diff folder1 folder2 > diff.patch
cd folder1
patch -p1 < diff.patch
```

Or you can use simple **diff** command...

```
diff -Naru folder1 folder2 > diff.patch
cd folder1
patch -p1 < diff.patch
```

here in both the case difference of folder1 and folder2 is going to apply on only folder1.